# Naming a Ruby method with an existing constant

Tags: ruby

```
module Foo
  def self.bar
    "Module.bar"
  end
end

def Foo
  "main.Foo"
end

puts Foo # Foo
puts Foo.bar # Module.bar
puts Foo() # main.Foo
puts Foo.class # Module
```

Why is it possible for the module `Foo` and the method `Foo` to coexist in the same namespace? Why doesn't the definition of the method `Foo` overwrite the module?

Comment: This question should be generalized: Why is it possible to have a method name that is the same as an existing constant **or local variable**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They don't exist in the same namespace. Constants and methods are in different namespaces. That's how they coexist. The language looks in the constant namespace unless you use the method-call parens, which unambiguously say "This is supposed to be a method."